# How to call model method in django view?

Tags: django

I'm trying to call a method in my Conversation model to get the latest message in my template. Here's my model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Conversation(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def get_last_message(self):
        lastmessage = Message.objects.filter(conversation=self).order_by('id')[0]

        return lastmessage


class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="sender")
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="recipient")
    text = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

And here is my template:

```
  {% for conversation in conversations %}
        <p>{{ conversation.get_latest_message.text }}</p>
```

I don't see any errors but there isn't any output. I can display the conversation.participants fine, but the call to the `get_latest_message` method doesn't do anything.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: last but not least it should be 'conversation.get_last_message' shouldn't it?

Comment: oh my goodness....that's exactly what it was...

Comment: I don't want to comment on how long I stared at that. Having a second set of eyes to review definitely helps! Thank you so much lol

Comment: I 100% feel you :D happend, will happen again.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need the `.text` part, just use `conversation.get_latest_message`

Comment: I'd suggest not relying on the `__str__` method in templates as it can be difficult to tell where it's all being used if you need to change it in the future.